# turn off liquibase logging at tomcat startup

Tags: java, log4j, log4j2, liquibase

I want to turn off liquibase logging when tomcat is starting up.

Here is my log4j2.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN" monitorInterval="30">
    <Properties>
        <Property name="LOG_PATTERN">
            %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%-5level] [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n
        </Property>
    </Properties>

    <Appenders>
        <Console name="ConsoleAppender" target="SYSTEM_OUT" follow="true">
            <PatternLayout pattern="${LOG_PATTERN}"/>
        </Console>

        <!-- Rolling File Appender -->
        <RollingFile name="FileAppender" fileName="logs/test.log"
                     filePattern="logs/test-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log">
            <PatternLayout>
                <Pattern>${LOG_PATTERN}</Pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1"/>
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="10MB"/>
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="10"/>
        </RollingFile>

    </Appenders>

    <Loggers>
        <Root level="info">
            <AppenderRef ref="ConsoleAppender"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="FileAppender"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

log4j2 spits out many logs and this is one of the logs which I want to turn off (**liquibase.servicelocator**)

```
17:31:14.690 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG liquibase.servicelocator.DefaultPackageScanClassResolver - Loaded the class: class liquibase.datatype.core.BlobType in classloader: jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@77556fd
17:31:14.691 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG liquibase.servicelocator.DefaultPackageScanClassResolver - Loaded the class: class liquibase.datatype.core.NVarcharType in classloader: jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@77556fd
17:31:14.691 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG liquibase.servicelocator.DefaultPackageScanClassResolver - Loaded the class: class liquibase.datatype.core.SmallIntType in classloader: jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@77556fd
17:31:14.691 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG liquibase.servicelocator.DefaultPackageScanClassResolver - Loaded the class: class liquibase.datatype.core.UnknownType in classloader: jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@77556fd
17:31:14.691 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG liquibase.servicelocator.DefaultPackageScanClassResolver - Loaded the class: class liquibase.datatype.core.TimeType in classloader: jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@77556fd
17:31:14.692 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG liquibase.servicelocator.DefaultPackageScanClassResolver - Loaded the class: interface liquibase.datatype.DataTypeInfo in classloader: jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@77556fd
17:31:14.692 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG liquibase.servicelocator.DefaultPackageScanClassResolver - Loaded the class: class liquibase.datatype.DataTypeFactory$1 in classloader: jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@77556fd
17:31:14.692 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG liquibase.servicelocator.DefaultPackageScanClassResolver - Loaded the class: class liquibase.datatype.core.VarcharType in classloader: jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@77556fd
17:31:14.692 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG liquibase.servicelocator.DefaultPackageScanClassResolver - Loaded the class: class liquibase.datatype.core.BooleanType in classloader: jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@77556fd
17:31:14.693 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG liquibase.servicelocator.DefaultPackageScanClassResolver - Loaded the class: class liquibase.datatype.core.XMLType in classloader: jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@77556fd
17:31:14.693 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG liquibase.servicelocator.DefaultPackageScanClassResolver - Loaded the class: class liquibase.datatype.core.MediumIntType in classloader: jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@77556fd
17:31:14.693 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG liquibase.servicelocator.DefaultPackageScanClassResolver - Loaded the class: class liquibase.datatype.core.DateType in classloader: jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@77556fd
17:31:14.693 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG liquibase.servicelocator.DefaultPackageScanClassResolver - Loaded the class: class liquibase.datatype.core.DateTimeType in classloader: jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@77556fd
17:31:14.693 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG liquibase.servicelocator.DefaultPackageScanClassResolver - Loaded the class: class liquibase.datatype.core.NumberType in classloader: jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@77556fd
17:31:14.693 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG liquibase.servicelocator.DefaultPackageScanClassResolver - Loaded the class: class liquibase.datatype.core.DoubleType in classloader: jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@77556fd
17:31:14.694 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG liquibase.servicelocator.DefaultPackageScanClassResolver - Loaded the class: class liquibase.datatype.core.ClobType in classloader: jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@77556fd
17:31:14.694 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG liquibase.servicelocator.DefaultPackageScanClassResolver - Loaded the class: class liquibase.datatype.core.FloatType in classloader: jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@77556fd
17:31:14.694 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG liquibase.servicelocator.DefaultPackageScanClassResolver - Loaded the class: class liquibase.datatype.core.CharType in classloader: jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@77556fd
17:31:14.694 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG liquibase.servicelocator.DefaultPackageScanClassResolver - Loaded the class: class liquibase.datatype.core.DatabaseFunctionType in classloader: jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@77556fd
17:31:14.694 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG liquibase.servicelocator.DefaultPackageScanClassResolver - Loaded the class: class liquibase.datatype.LiquibaseDataType in classloader: jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@77556fd
17:31:14.694 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG liquibase.servicelocator.DefaultPackageScanClassResolver - Loaded the class: class liquibase.datatype.core.UUIDType in classloader: jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@77556fd
17:31:14.695 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG liquibase.servicelocator.DefaultPackageScanClassResolver - Loaded the class: class liquibase.datatype.DatabaseDataType in classloader: jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@77556fd
17:31:14.695 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG liquibase.servicelocator.DefaultPackageScanClassResolver - Loaded the class: class liquibase.datatype.core.DecimalType in classloader: jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@77556fd
17:31:14.695 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG liquibase.servicelocator.DefaultPackageScanClassResolver - Loaded the class: class liquibase.datatype.core.TinyIntType in classloader: jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@77556fd
17:31:14.696 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG liquibase.servicelocator.DefaultPackageScanClassResolver - Loaded the class: class liquibase.datatype.DataTypeFactory in classloader: jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@77556fd
17:31:14.696 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG liquibase.servicelocator.DefaultPackageScanClassResolver - Loaded the class: class liquibase.datatype.core.NCharType in classloader: jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@77556fd
17:31:14.696 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG liquibase.servicelocator.DefaultPackageScanClassResolver - Loaded the class: class liquibase.datatype.core.IntType in classloader: jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@77556fd
17:31:14.696 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG liquibase.servicelocator.DefaultPackageScanClassResolver - Loaded the class: class liquibase.datatype.core.CurrencyType in classloader: jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@77556fd
```

Comment: Either these logs are not coming through Log4j2 or it isn’t using your configuration as the logs don’t match your pattern.

Comment: that is correct, it does not match. So it is not using my log4j2 configurations. In this case, any idea on how to turn off these logs?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know what Liquibase uses for logging. I would have to look at either the Liquibase documentation or source code to determine that.